# How to make JavaScript basic shopping cart amount calculator

Tags: javascript, cart, shopping-cart

```html
 <script>
  var itemquantity, appleamount, appletotalamount, bananaamount, bananatotalamount, gtotalfruits, gtotalfruitss

  function apple() {
    var itemquantity = document.getElementById("apple");
    var appleamount = document.getElementById("appletotal");
    var appletotalamount = itemquantity.value * 50;
    appleamount.value = appletotalamount;
  }

  function banana() {
    var itemquantity = document.getElementById("banana");
    var bananaamount = document.getElementById("bananatotal");
    var bananatotalamount = itemquantity.value * 30;
    bananaamount.value = bananatotalamount;
  }

  function grandtotalfruits() {
    var gtotalfruits = document.getElementById("grandtotalfruitss");
    var gtotalfruitss = appletotalamount + bananatotalamount;
    gtotalfruits.value = gtotalfruitss;
  }
</script>

<div class="left">
  <p class="fruit11">Apples - <input type="number" id="apple" class="shoppinginput" onChange="apple()" onchange="grandtotalfruits"> Rs.50/Kg</p>
  <p class="fruit12">Total amount = Rs.<output id="appletotal"></output></p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p class="fruit11">Bananas - <input type="number" id="banana" class="shoppinginput" onChange="banana()" onchange="grandtotalfruits"> Rs.30/Kg</p>
  <p class="fruit12">Total amount = Rs.<output id="bananatotal"></output></p>
</div>

<div class="grandtotal">
  <p class="fruit13">Grand total = Rs.<output id="grandtotalfruitss"></output></p>
</div>`
```

Take first input type="number" value1 * 100 show in output box and then take input type="number" value2 * 100 show in second output box, then add the value1 and value2 and show in output box 3. I am using JavaScript and am a beginner.

Can you see the design while reading the question?

It's working for output1 and output2, but not able create correct method or function for the grand total output of output1 and output2 in the third output box.

Comment: 'can u see the design while reading the question?' No I can't -- you should post your code.

Comment: what specifically are you asking because at the moment it is a little unclear

Comment: can you show your input and output example?

Comment: yes.......here it is..half is working i need to add apple and banana value and show in grand total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what @dev8989 said. Every time the user changes the "apples" value, you change the "apples quantity" (same for the "bananas"). You also have to update the "grand total" if any of the apples/bananas are updated. That's what @dev8989 suggested:

```js
var $apples = document.getElementById('apples')
var $applesTotal = document.getElementById('apples-total')
var $bananas = document.getElementById('bananas')
var $bananasTotal = document.getElementById('bananas-total')
var $grandTotal = document.getElementById('grand-total')

function apple (v) { return 50 * v }
function banana (v) { return 30 * v}

$apples.addEventListener('change', function() {
  $applesTotal.textContent = apple($apples.value)
  $grandTotal.textContent = apple($apples.value) + banana($bananas.value)
})
$bananas.addEventListener('change', function() {
  $bananasTotal.textContent = banana($bananas.value)
  $grandTotal.textContent = apple($apples.value) + banana($bananas.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="apples">
<p>Apples total: <span id="apples-total">0</span></p>
<input type="number" id="bananas">
<p>Bananas total: <span id="bananas-total">0</span></p>
<p>Grand total: <span id="grand-total">0</span></p>
```

---

*Edit:* here's the original code with the bugs fixed. See my comment on why this was necessary:

```js
var itemquantity, appleamount, appletotalamount = 0, bananaamount, bananatotalamount = 0, gtotalfruits, gtotalfruitss

function apple() {
  var itemquantity = document.getElementById("apple");
  var appleamount = document.getElementById("appletotal");
  appletotalamount = itemquantity.value * 50;
  appleamount.value = appletotalamount;
  grandtotalfruits();
}

function banana() {
  var itemquantity = document.getElementById("banana");
  var bananaamount = document.getElementById("bananatotal");
  bananatotalamount = itemquantity.value * 30;
  bananaamount.value = bananatotalamount;
  grandtotalfruits();
}

function grandtotalfruits() {
  var gtotalfruits = document.getElementById("grandtotalfruitss");
  var gtotalfruitss = appletotalamount + bananatotalamount;
  gtotalfruits.value = gtotalfruitss;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <p class="fruit11">Apples - <input type="number" id="apple" class="shoppinginput" onChange="apple()" onchange="grandtotalfruits"> Rs.50/Kg</p>
  <p class="fruit12">Total amount = Rs.<output id="appletotal"></output></p>
</div>
<div class="left">
  <p class="fruit11">Bananas - <input type="number" id="banana" class="shoppinginput" onChange="banana()" onchange="grandtotalfruits"> Rs.30/Kg</p>
  <p class="fruit12">Total amount = Rs.<output id="bananatotal"></output></p>
</div>

<div class="grandtotal">
  <p class="fruit13">Grand total = Rs.<output id="grandtotalfruitss"></output></p>
```

Comment: i smiled after the program worked in your snippet. but u see the type of programming i have written. your pattern of coding i m trying to fit in my pattern. thank you..let see

Comment: just trying to say..its been only 3 days tht i started learning javascript. lill above my head...sorry

Comment: Ok so: first thing you got to call `grandtotalfruits()` in `apple()` and `banana()` like @dev8989 suggested. But: your `grandtotalfruits` accesses the "global" variables `appletotalamount` and `bananatotalamount`, which are never actually set to anything, because the ones you set in `apple`/`banana`  are new variables local to the scope of these functions. Long story short, second thing you have to remove the `var` before them in apple/banana. I'll edit my post.

Comment: thnx..fixed it now...and i displayed the grandtotalfruits in main grandtotal output which will show grandtotalfruits grandtotalvegs grandtotalnonveg grandtotalsnacks. this started with some small input js example on w3school.....and reached here,,..thnk you...:)

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer so that others find a working answer if they come with a similar problem. Merry Christmas!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304932/read-image-slidercycle-loop-onmouseover-image-thumbnail-stop-on-mouseout-j @Dominik Schreiber

Answer (score 1):

Add the `grandtotalfruit()` in the `apple()` and `banana()` functions.

```
 function apple() {
        var itemquantity = document.getElementById("apple");
        var appleamount = document.getElementById("appletotal");
        var appletotalamount = itemquantity.value * 50;
        appleamount.value = appletotalamount;
        grandtotalfruit();
      }

      function banana() {
        var itemquantity = document.getElementById("banana");
        var bananaamount = document.getElementById("bananatotal");
        var bananatotalamount = itemquantity.value * 30;
        bananaamount.value = bananatotalamount;
        grandtotalfruit();
      }
```