# Image slider (cycle-loop) onmouseover image-thumbnail, stop on mouseout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have made a simple thumbnail image showcase to preview in #imgbig viewer. I hover on thumbnail it shows it in the image box. I have five different thumbnails.

Sorry for not including images here. When I do mouseover on thumbnail I want it to show the image slider in the #imgbig instead of the same pic.

It will show an image (cycle) slider matching the pic of the same thumbnail in different angles either from an array of image loop or images from the folder.

Like an image showcase, showing the thumbnail image in different angles inside the #imgbig when the thumbnail is onmouseover and goes back to default image onmouseout.

For now I have added an image slider with matching images with the first thumbnail and the slider in its #imgbig is working too.

But I am not to keep the slider in stop position till I mouseover the image. It starts playing as soon I load the page and it gets faster in loop when I mouseover the image and keeps getting faster in loop.

```js
var i = 1;

function slider() {
  var imgg = document.getElementById("imgbig");
  imgg.src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=" + i;
  i++;
  if (i > 10) {
    i = 1;
  }
}
function timer()
{
setInt = setInterval(slider,1000);
}
function slideroff()
{
i=1;
clearInterval(setInt);
var imgg=document.getElementById("imgbig");
imgg.src = "http://placehold.it/400x400";
}
```

```css
.imgboxdiv {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.imageshowcase {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: ;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.imageshowcase img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.imgparameter {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

*
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color:slategrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Title </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="imgboxdiv">
    <h1>Image slider start on mouseover thumbnail</h1>

    <div class="imageshowcase" id="imgshwcase">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" id="imgbig">
    </div>

    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1"  onmouseover="slider()" id="img1" class="imgparameter">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Of the two questions I can see in your profile, they are/were likely to attract downvotes because (a) they appear to have been composed on a mobile phone, being written in all-lower-case; (b) you sometimes use txtspk, (c) you add voting commentary or advice intended to discourage the normal use of the voting functions here. I would recommend that you write your questions as carefully as possible, paying attention to case and spelling, and keep them succinct and free of chat. Make sure you read [ask] too, if you have not already done so.

Comment: What does "Sorry for no images in realtime" mean? I am confused by this.

Comment: i mean i couldn't attach the images in this code here. so the snippet runs blank...sorry...

Comment: I just need this thing to work out for my class project... I literally asked in many sites n searched on google.... however the process in which i need the slider to work... doesn't seem to be fixed or tried or asked or created by anyone i guess....n i am just a month old in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it myself..

```js
var i = 1;
var setInt;

function  slider()
{
 var imgg=document.getElementById("imgbig");
 imgg.src = "https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=" + i ;
 i++;
 if(i>5)
 {
 i=1;
 }
}
function timer()
{
 setInt = setInterval(slider,2000);
}
function slideroff()
{
 i=1;
 clearInterval(setInt);
 var imgg=document.getElementById("imgbig");
 imgg.src = "http://placehold.it/400x400";
}
```

```css
*
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

body
{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:0;
 background-color:slategrey;
}

.imgboxdiv
{
 width:1000px;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
.imageshowcase
{
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 background-color:;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
.imageshowcase img
{
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 border:3px solid red;
}
.imgparameter
{
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 border:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> Title </title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="imgboxdiv" >
<h1>Image slider start on mouseover thumbnail</h1>

<div class="imageshowcase" id="imgshwcase">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" id="imgbig">
</div>

<img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?random=1" onmouseover="timer()" onmouseout="slideroff()" id="img1" class="imgparameter">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i feel guilty since i had not found the reason behind the comment.Please forgive me and happy coding :)